# Moving cursor using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

I would like to **move the cursor** to a given x,y coordinates of the MapCanvas.

Is there an easy way to do this using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move cursor like that:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

cursor = QCursor()
cursor.setPos(100, 200)
```

It moves your cursor to point 100,200 in your screen. If you want to get coordinate of a point on the map canvas, you need to translate them:

```
# coordinates of point on map canvas
point = QPoint(100,100)
# translate widget coordinates to global screen coordinates
global_point = iface.mapCanvas().mapToGlobal(QPoint(100,100))
# set cursor to these coords
cursor.setPos(global_point.x(), global_point.y())
```

Comment: +1, I spent a little time trying to find this but couldn't. Also great that you added a translation for the map canvas coordinates =)

Comment: `mapToGlobal()`, eh? how cool is that!!! answers my question too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217164/pyqgis-convert-screen-to-map-coordinates

Comment: Hey! Is that possible to convert map point to canvas point? I mean for example `QgsPointXY(34.364272,44.61443)` to `QPoint(x,y)`