# PyQgis convert screen to map coordinates

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, coordinates, convert, qpoint

With PyQgis how can I convert absolute screen coordinates (say, `123,456`) into map coordinates of the `iface.mapCanvas`?

It would be no problem if I had screen coordinates relative to the `iface.mapCanvas.viewport()`, since `iface.mapCanvas.viewport().geometry()` gives me sth like `QRect(2,2,2198, 1090)` and `iface.mapCanvas().extent()` gives me a `QgsRectangle` with `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax`, so (leaving projection issues out of the scope) the conversion would be simple.

But since the absolute position of the `mapCanvas` may vary with toolbar positions or layer windows width, the question reduces to 'how to derive the absolute screen position of the map canvas?'.

Comment: I think [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/154793/37413) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mapToGlobal(), which takes a QPoint as its argument. For example:

```
map_coor = iface.mapCanvas().mapToGlobal(QPoint(123, 456))
```

I couldn't find QGIS API documentation, but I'm guessing this inherits from QWidget through the map canvas and Python interface: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal.

Answer (score 4):

`mapToGlobal()` function gives me global screen coordinates. The next code works for me:

```
pScreen = QPoint(123, 456)
pMap = iface.mapCanvas().getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(pScreen)
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I needed as well - the accepted answer is just converting the canvas coordinate to a screen coordinate wheras this converts a canvas coordinate to a world coordinate - it even uses the current layer's CRS which saved me a ton of work